# Combining jQuery and Pixastic

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, blur

I just want to click on the image and then see it blur out. That's it. Here is the link:

http://www.olliemccarthy.com/test/blur-experiment/

Here is the code I've been using so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.test').click(function() {

  $(this).("blurfast", {amount:0.8})

 });

});
```

I've tried rearranging the order in which the scripts are called in and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).pixastic("blurfast", {amount:0.8});
```

will do it. You forgot to call the `jQuery method`.

Comment: Ah, it was unedited when I last saw it -- not that I was giving you anything but a friendly chiding. :-)

Comment: @OllieMcCarthy: If this answered your question, please be sure to tick the checkmark just to the left of the beginning of his answer. That marks the question answered (and credits jAndy with having been the person who answered it).

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the code I've been using so far.
>   
>  [snip]
>   
>  `$(this).("blurfast", {amount:0.8})`

That's invalid JavaScript syntax and should be throwing a parsing error.

According to the [Pixtastic documentation](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/#jquery), you want:

```
$(this).pixastic("blurfast", {amount:0.8});
```

...assuming that you want to blur the image that was clicked.